# Fixed The position of marquee at footer flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i am use

SingleChildScrollView in my code then it is possible to set container position fixed to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bottom fixed [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

It will display at the bottom of an app for selecting among a small number of views,